# Snowflake create partition based on file column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Is it possible to create partition in external tables in snowflake based on the file column instead of using file path (`metadata$filename`) when the file folder isn't partitioned.

I have tried creating an external like exemple bellow:

```
create or replace external table "db"."schema".EXT_TABLE (
    "year" NUMBER(38,0) AS YEAR(TO_TIMESTAMP((PARSE_JSON(VALUE:"c3"):"time":"$date"::varchar)))
    )
    partition by ("year")
    partition_type = user_specified 
    location=@stage
    file_format=file_format;
```

but it returns the error `Function GET is not supported in an external table partition column expression.`

I also have tried using the `(parse_json(metadata$external_table_partition)` as documentation shows, but this column always returns empty.

Does anyone have any tips that can make it works ?